# Dirichlet kernel.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have a function $h\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$, and I want to show that:

$$\int_{\pi\geq |t|>\delta>0} h(x+t)D_N(t) dt/2\pi \leq \xi_N(h,\delta)$$

where $\xi_N(h,\delta) \rightarrow 0$ as $N\rightarrow \infty$.

($D_N$ is Dirichlet kernel).

This question arises from Riemann Localization principle where we have two $L^1$ functions that agree on a $\delta$ nbhd of $x$, and thus their partial Fourier sums, their difference converges to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a consequence of the following local convergence theorem for Fourier series, taken from [Fourier Analysis, an Introduction by Stein & Shakarchi](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/7562.html), page 81:

**Theorem 2.1** Let $f$ be an integrable function on the circle which is differentiable at a point $\theta_0$. Then $S_N(f)(\theta_0)\to f(\theta_0)$ as $N$ tends to in infinity.

Here $S_N(f)$ is he $N$-th partial sum of the Fourier series of $f$. A key ingredient in the proof is the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. It can be generalized to weaker conditions on $f$, like Dini's criterion.

Now to your question. We may assume without loss of generality hat $x=0$. let $h_\delta$ be defined by
$$h_\delta(x)=\begin{cases}
h(x) & \text{if }\delta<|x|\le\pi,\\
0 & \text{if }|x|\le\delta.
\end{cases}$$
Then $h_\delta$ is integrable, is differentiable in a neighborhood of $0$ and hence
$$
S_N(h_\delta)(0)=\frac{1}{2\,\pi}\int_{\pi\ge|t|>\delta} h(t)D_N(t)\,dt\to0\text{ as }N\to\infty.
$$